# expand.grid() based on values in two variables in R

Tags: r, variables, expand, r-grid

I would like to expand a grid in R such that the expansion occurs for unique values of one variable but joint values for two variables. For example:

```
frame <- data.frame(id = seq(1:2),id2 = seq(1:2), year = c(2005, 2008))
```

I would like to expand the frame for each year, but such that id and id2 are considered jointly (e.g. (1,1), and (2,2) to generate an output like:

```
  id id2 year
   1  1   2005
   1  1   2006
   1  1   2007
   1  1   2005
   2  2   2006
   2  2   2007
   2  2   2008
```

Using expand.grid(), does someone know how to do this? I have not been able to wrangle the code past looking at each id uniquely and producing a frame with all combinations given the following code:

```
 with(frame, expand.grid(year = seq(min(year), max(year)), id = unique(id), id2 = unique(id2)))
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `reshape::expand.grid.df`

```
require(reshape)
expand.grid.df(data.frame(id=1:2,id2=1:2), data.frame(year=c(2005:2008)))
> expand.grid.df(data.frame(id=1:2,id2=1:2), data.frame(year=c(2005:2008)))
  id id2 year
1  1   1 2005
2  2   2 2005
3  1   1 2006
4  2   2 2006
5  1   1 2007
6  2   2 2007
7  1   1 2008
8  2   2 2008
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `base R`

```
 indx <- diff(frame$year)+1
 indx1 <- rep(1:nrow(frame), each=indx)
 frame1 <- transform(frame[indx1,1:2], year=seq(frame$year[1], length.out=indx, by=1))
 row.names(frame1) <- NULL
  frame1
  #  id id2 year
  #1  1   1 2005
  #2  1   1 2006
  #3  1   1 2007
  #4  1   1 2008
  #5  2   2 2005
  #6  2   2 2006
  #7  2   2 2007
  #8  2   2 2008
```

Comment: Would there be a more efficient way to do this based on `data.table` ?

Comment: @RafaelPereira  You may use the `CJ` similar to the expand.grid showed in the other post